# How can I make my web app more robust to handle unexpected traffic spikes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, heroku, cdn

I asked this on HN but didn't get much advice.

I'm a n00b in web app development. Nevertheless, I've been working on an app (in Ruby on Rails + deployed with Heroku) that has gotten some really positive feedback, so I'd like to dedicated more resources to it.

However, I'm not a sysadmin or anything of the sort, so I'm unsure as to **what steps to take** to ensure my app is robust and can handle unexpected traffic spikes without crashing.

Essentially, I'd like to prepare for the worst-case scenario in terms of handling unexpected traffic spikes etc.

Any specific pointers (especially with Heroku) will be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the overall distribution of http requests for loading a typical page on your app? Open that in Mozilla Firebug / Chrome Dev Tool and analyze http requests being made.

If you see that there are LOTS of static content being loaded (Like CSS / images/ JS ) for each page then it would indicate a cache issue (static content are not getting cached).

You could even move static content to a CDN (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) These two are low hanging fruits.

next step is to ensure that your app can be hosted on multiple machines (E.g. it does not depend on same http session across each host and similar things). This way you can add more hosts to serve the demand.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure your app is stable during all development and deployments, write unit tests, functional tests and integration tests (there are a lot of gems to handle this, like shoulda, rspec, cucumber, capybara, selenium...).

I would also use Hoptoad for error notification. There is a free offer for 1 project ( https://hoptoadapp.com/account/new/Egg )

The next thing to monitor your site could be NewRelic ( http://newrelic.com/ ). It gives you an overview what queries took long and where is a bottleneck in your app.

Answer (score 0):

A very short answer: In theory you need to learn about **capacity**, **scalability** and **performance**.
On practice you can spin up more instances on heroku (or engines) but you'll be paying more money for it.